# Get webpack sourcemaps for both js and scss files

Tags: javascript, webpack, source-maps

I'm learning using Webpack in my app.
So far so good, but for now, I'm unable to have correct sourcempas for both javascript files and style fles (scss).

Here is how I'm using it (with firefox 50 under ubuntu).

Package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
  "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
  "jquery": "^3.1.1"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "babel-core": "^6.2.1",
  "babel-eslint": "^7.1.1",
  "babel-loader": "^6.2.0",
  "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.1.18",
  "css-loader": "^0.21.0",
  "eslint": "^3.13.0",
  "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "^11.0.1",
  "eslint-loader": "^1.6.1",
  "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.2.0",
  "exports-loader": "^0.6.3",
  "expose-loader": "^0.7.1",
  "extract-file-loader": "^0.1.0",
  "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^0.8.2",
  "file-loader": "^0.8.4",
  "html-loader": "^0.4.4",
  "html-webpack-plugin": "^1.6.2",
  "image-webpack-loader": "^2.0.0",
  "imports-loader": "^0.7.0",
  "jscs": "^3.0.7",
  "jscs-loader": "^0.3.0",
  "lodash": "^4.17.4",
  "node-sass": "^3.7.0",
  "null-loader": "^0.1.1",
  "postcss-loader": "^0.7.0",
  "resolve-url-loader": "^1.6.1",
  "sass-loader": "^3.2.0",
  "style-loader": "^0.13.0",
  "url-loader": "^0.5.7",
  "webpack": "^1.13.2",
  "webpack-dev-server": "^1.15"
}
```

webpack.config.js:

```
...
plugins: [new ExtractTextPlugin('styles.css')],
...
preLoaders: [{test: /\.js$/, loaders: ['eslint']},
...
loaders: [
    { test: /(\.jsx|\.js)$/, loader: 'babel', exclude: /node_modules/ },
    { test: /\.css$/, loader: "style-loader!css-loader?sourceMap" },
    { test: /\.scss/, loader: 'style-loader!css-loader?sourceMap!resolve-url-loader!sass-loader?sourceMap' },
    { test  : /\.woff(2)?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/, loader: 'url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff' },
    { test  : /\.(ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/, loader: 'file-loader'}
],
...
debug: true,
devtool: 'source-map',
...
```

My entry point (index.js), there are just those lines :

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import '../scss/main.scss';

$('body').append('<div class="test1">test1</div>');

console.info('app loaded');
```

And my scss files :

```
@import '~bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap';
@import '~font-awesome/scss/font-awesome';
```

So, I tried every values of devtool options (eval, source-map, inline-source-map, etc ....),
But none seems to let me have :

- the correct files names (js and scss)
- the correct line numbers (js    and scss)

For example, with **devtool: 'eval-source-map'**,
Firefox dev tool shows me for js files :

```
(i) app loaded ---------------- main.js%20line%201051%20%3E%20eval:13:1
```

instead of :

```
(i) app loaded ---------------- index.js:6:1
```

and for scss files :

```
.fa-3x { ---------------- _larger.scss:11
```

Which is correct.

And the with **devtool: 'eval'**

The javacsript log in firefox is showing

```
(i) app loaded ---------------- index.js?:13:1
```

File name is correct but not number line

And with styles :

```
.fa-3x { ---------------- blob:http://localhost:8001/f010a6f5-ac3a-4e2c-a3d1-fd3a57ff949b
```

The filenam is totally wrong.

So how can I have some useful sourcemaps for my environnement ?
I don't even car if buiding is slow as the values are correct ...

Thanks in advance